# transform broadcasting to something calculateable. matrix np.multipy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, optimization

I'm trying to calculate this type of calculation:

```
arr = np.arange(4) 
# array([0, 1, 2, 3])

arr_t =arr.reshape((-1,1))
# array([[0],
#        [1],
#        [2],
#        [3]])

mult_arr = np.multiply(arr,arr_t) # <<< the multiplication
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3],
#        [0, 2, 4, 6],
#        [0, 3, 6, 9]])
```

to eventually perform it in a bigger matrix index of single row, and to sum all the matrices that are reproduced by the calculation:

```
arr = np.random.random((600,150))

arr_t =arr.reshape((-1,arr.shape[1],1))


mult = np.multiply(arr[:,None],arr_t)
summed = np.sum(mult,axis=0)
summed
```

Till now its all pure awesomeness, the problem starts when I try to covert on a bigger dataset, for example this array instead :

```
arr = np.random.random((6000,1500))
```

I get the following error - `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 101. GiB for an array with shape (6000, 1500, 1500) and data type float64`
which make sense, but my question is:

***can I get around this anyhow without being forced to use loops that slow down the process entirely ??***

my question is mainly about performance and solution that require long running tasks more then 30 secs is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are simply trying to perform a dot product:

```
arr.T@arr
```

or

```
arr.T.dot(arr)
```

###### checking this is what you want

```
arr = np.random.random((600,150))

arr_t =arr.reshape((-1,arr.shape[1],1))
mult = np.multiply(arr[:,None],arr_t)
summed = np.sum(mult,axis=0)

np.allclose((arr.T@arr), summed)
# True
```

Comment: can show mathematically how you figured it out?

Comment: It was more of an intuition at first, I saw you performed a broadcasted multiplication of the transposed matrix, then a sum, this is actually the definition of the matrix multiplication ;) You could also use `matmul`

Comment: out of too many programmatical problems my brain does not recognize math anymore... should refresh my mind asap